# Using Open Office to list time elapsed in months

Tags: formatting, database, time

I'm new to open office and using the spread sheet for a database of cattle on my farm.

I need it (amongst other things!) to be able to calculate the age of the cattle in months.  So, in column B I have the DOB listed.  I want colum C to take the DOB and then to autofill with the age in months.  Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You may want to upgrade to LibreOffice as Open Office is no longer in development and is basically dead.  http://www.libreoffice.org

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date is in Cell B1

In column C1 enter this formula:

```
=DATEDIF(B1,TODAY(),"m")
```